# How to create charts based on content types items?

Tags: 7, views, charts

I want to create a chart according to each content type created per month or week.

How can I do it? Is there any suggestion to use some module?

Comment: What do you want to chart? Items created by date,  right? And was you able to get a view of that and only need help with charting? Or you can chart but can't get data? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @Mołot yes items created by date and by content type.

Comment: Hi, we don't write tutorials here as they're too broad for the Q+A format. If you have a more specific question that fits the guidelines in the [help], please ask or separately. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using the Charts module

#### Step 1: Getting started

To create charts in Drupal, just use the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. It comes with a sample view which will give you a chart for each of your content types.

Just clone and refine that view, and check how close you are to make it fit your needs. Refer to [Create charts using Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313837) (and its subpages) for more details.

For a sample of such chart (derived from the delivered sample view), have a look at [this demo sample](http://drupal.placeto.be/charts/examples/views).

#### Step 2: Create the tabular format of the view

A common mistake when creating charts, is that the data to be charted is (not yet) correct. So you really need to first work on getting the tabular format of the view created correctly. That's also what's recommended in the ***Bonus tip*** within [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929), i.e.:

> You may find it easier to start with a "Table" display and convert it to a chart display after setting up the data. **It can be easier to visualize what the result of the chart will be if it's been laid out in a table first.** ...

#### Step 3: Add the chart to your view

Do not try to start this step if you didn't first complete the prior step.

There is an issue which might help to answer this question, or at least to understand the challenge here. I.e. [Graph node input over time (support date formatting on a continuous axis)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096).

In [Comment #3](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096#comment-7697321) of that issue is stated: 'The trouble here is that neither Views nor Date modules provide aggregation options for date-based fields.'.

## Using the Quant module

If using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module you can't get it to work (or don't want to consider the suggestions above), then you may want to look at the [Quant](https://www.drupal.org/project/quant) module as an alternative. Here are some excerpts from its project page:

> ... provides an engine for producing quantitative, time-based analytics for virtually any Drupal component. Quant takes raw data about normal Drupal actions, such as node creation, and plots the activity over time, with the selected time being configurable. See the screenshot provided for a better understanding.
>
> Provided charts:
>
> - Content creation
> - Comment creation
> - Content creation by type
> - Aggregate content creation
> - User creation
> - Page views (requires Statistics)
> - User shouts (requires Shoutbox)
> - User point transactions (requires User Points)
> - Group creation (requires Organic groups)
> - Group joins (requires Organic groups)
> - Invites sent (requires Invite)
> - Invites accepted (requires Invite)
> - Statuses shared (requires Facebook-style statuses)
> - Private messages (requires Private message)

Especially the "Page views* chart that is provided might be close to what you're looking for.

## Evaluating other charting modules

If none of the above modules would work in your case, then you might want to look at the "[Comparison of Charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985)" documentation.

Disclosure: I'm a (co-)maintainer of all modules mentioned above (and original author of the comparison).

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following module:

- [Statistics Pro](https://www.drupal.org/project/statspro)

  > This statistics module provides statistical results of nodes, comments and users. [Charts and Graphs](http://drupal.org/project/charts_graphs) module or the [Views Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_charts) module it enables specific features dependent on each one of these modules like page visualization reports and graphs.
  >
  > The [Statistics Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced) ([7.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/816040)) module should be used with Statistics Pro which provides a few advanced options to the core Statistics module.

Comment: "Statistics Advanced" does not have a D7 version (which this question is about ...). Therefor, IMHO, the last parg does not apply (since this question is about D7).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Added link to 7.x version which needs some review. This is optional module to use.